# States on population

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A person has been declared the first to inhabit a certain planet on day $N = 0$. For each positive integer $N > 0$, if there is a positive number of people on the planet, then either one of the following three occurs, each with probability $1/3$:
>
> (i) the population stays the same;
>
> (ii) the population increases by $2^N$;
>
> (iii) the population decreases by $2^{N−1}$ (If there are no greater than $2^{N−1}$ people on the planet, the population drops to zero, and the process terminates.)
>
> Find the probability that at some point there are exactly $2^{20} + 2^{19} + 2^{10} + 2^9 + 1$ people.

I believe this is an infinite game, so I decided to use states. However, I can't find a way to list a group of equations because of so many cases. One thing I noticed is the 1 means that nothing happens on the first day. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'd start by describing some good paths.  It's not so easy to find one.  You need to increase rapidly at the start, and then of course you need to cancel off the low terms you added.

Comment: Is this possible: On day $5$ there is population $1$ (the population has stayed the same each day so far).  On the next day (day $N=6$), the population decreases by $2^{6-1}=32$.  Now the population is $-31$.  What does this mean?

Comment: @paw88789  as I understand the rules, that particular path can't happen.  On day $N=2$ you;'d have one person which is $2N-1=3$, so the population would zero out and the game would stop.  Of course, I don't know if the OP meant to write $2^{N-1}$ in that condition or not....if $2N-1$ really was intended then, of course, you can find paths that do go negative.

Comment: Thanks lulu, I missed the $2N-1$ extinction condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will call the events $A$ - population stays the same; $B$ - population increases by $2^N$; and $C$ - population decreases by $2^{N-1}$ where $N$ is the day number.

First notice that a $2^n$ term in the total population can only come from event $B$ on day $n$. So a population of $2^{20}+2^{19}+2^{10}+2^{9}+1$ means there must have been an event $B$ on days $9,10,19,20$. We cannot reach that population before day $20$. And if we don't reach it on day $20$, we won't get *exactly* that population on any later day.

So we can replace the original question with a new question "How many sequences of $20$ daily events result in a population of $2^{20}+2^{19}+2^{10}+2^{9}+1$ on day $20$ ?". There are $3^{20}$ different sequences of $20$ daily events and each one is equally likely, so to find the final probability we just divide the number of possible sequences by $3^{20}$.

So what can happen on days $1$ to $8$ ? We want the population to still be $1$ at the end of day $8$. Well, we can have event $A$ on any of these days. But if we have event $B$ on day $n$ then it must be followed by event $C$ on day $n+1$ to remove the $2^n$ term from the population. And if we have event $C$ on any day that is not immediately after event $B$ on the previous day then the population drops to zero and the sequence ends.

So the next question is how many sequences of $8$ daily events are there in which each $B$ (if there are any) is followed by a $C$, and each $C$ (if there are any) is immediately preceded by a $B$ ? You can work this out by finding a recursion formula (hint: think about the Fibonacci sequence).

Suppose there are $x$ possible sequences of events on days $1$ to $8$. Then there are also $x$ possible sequences for days $11$ to $18$. So the total number of possible sequences for days $1$ to $20$ is $x^2$ and the probability of one of these sequences occuring is $\frac{x^2}{3^{20}}$.

Comment: Thanks! This really made things much more clear! 

My recursion:
Let $F_n$ be the number of paths on day $n$. We know $F_1=F_2=1$ (A's for both.)
Consider $F_n$. The last event could be an C or an A. An A would mean $F_{n-1}$, while a C means a B before and thus $F_{n-2}$.
So $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$. The 8th fibonacci number is 21, so our probablity is 
$$\frac{49}{3^{18}}.$$

Comment: @Qwerty987 You have the right idea but you made one small error. The number of possible sequences for $2$ days is $2$ - either $AA$ or $BC$. And $F_3=2$. So the number of possible sequences for $8$ days is $F_9$, not $F_8$.